# Unable to access the openvpn Access Web Ui

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I followed [this](https://openvpn.net/download-open-vpn/) OpenVPN installation guide,
and did all the steps and successfully installed openvpn

output:

```
To reconfigure manually, use the /usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init tool.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Access Server 2.11.1 has been successfully installed in /usr/local/openvpn_as
Configuration log file has been written to /usr/local/openvpn_as/init.log


Access Server Web UIs are available here:
Admin  UI: https://{ip}:943/admin
Client UI: https://{ip}:943/
To login please use the "openvpn" account with "TPuID9RkAuGP" password.
(password can be changed on Admin UI)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

But when I visit `https://{ip}:943/admin` or `https://{ip}:943` the broswer timeout and I get no response back, I tried searching on solutions online but so far I didn't find any fixes.

I tried:

1. [Troubleshooting access to the web interface](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-access-to-the-web-interface/#after-initial-installation-web-interface-cannot-be-reached)

`netstat -tulpn` Output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State                                                                                                                    PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:904           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:905           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:906           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:907           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:908           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:909           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:943             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50562/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   13854/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   806/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                   50599/openvpn-opens
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                   806/sshd: /usr/sbin
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                                        13854/systemd-resol
udp        0      0 {ip}:68        0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                                        13837/systemd-netwo
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                                                        50609/openvpn-opens
```

2. I tried restarting `openvpn-as`
3. I tried to reran the `ovpn-init`

   [Why can't I access the adminclient ui](https://openvpn.net/faq/why-cant-i-access-the-adminclient-ui/)

```
/usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init --force
```

Nothing worked so far. how can i fix it.

System information:
Linux 5.4..
-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP x86_64

Comment: Hi @0xmemo21 please edit your question and add the output of `iptables -L INPUT -n -v`. Thanks.